# Using standalone infinispan and JGroups not forming a cluster with UDP

Tags: multicast, infinispan, jgroups

I am using standalone infinispan server on linux.
We have bundled the infinispan version 7.1.1.Final. lWe have provided the UDP multicast IP and Port through cluster.xml file.I have 8 node in the cluster.But jgroup is not forming the cluster. Each node has infinispan running as individuals with different bind address. Same setup is done for different deployment and it is running normally. There are no errors and warnings in the infinispan logs.
Each node has only one member in the cluster view with their individual host and IP address

eg:
**2021-06-26 00:18:51,697 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-25) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel clustered: [server1/clustered|0] (1) [server1/clustered]**

Below things I have investigated, suspecting that can we multicast issue:

1. Able to get all jgroup IP's and they are of same subnet
2. Run the tcpdump command to check the communication between bind address and multicast address and able to receive the UDP packets
3. All the bind address are of bridge br3. So checked that if all the br3 of all node is connected to same interface. It was connected to same interface
4. Checked the multicast snooping is disable or not. It should be disable to form cluster. It was disabled

kindly provide some insights for this investigation.

Comment: Could you please update the Infinispan version to 12.1.6.Final ?

Comment: Sorry, I wont be able to update the infinispan version currently as it is used by many applications

Comment: You can check if multicasting works with iperf: https://serverfault.com/questions/294207/how-can-i-test-multicast-udp-connectivity-between-two-servers

Comment: Jgrouos also includes a multicast test: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/4/html/ch07s07s11.html